# vim の ステータスバーに 入力ソースを表示することはできますか？

Tags: macos, vim

Mac の Terminal.app を利用しています。

vim の ステータスバーに「英語」「日本語」の入力ソースを表示したい。
なぜならば、 Terminal.app をフルスクリーンで表示しているため、現在の入力ソースがわからないからである。

回答をお待ちしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`に現在の入力ソースの状態が書かれているそうです.
[Determine OS X keyboard layout ("input source") in the terminal/a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21597804/10294107)
(入力ソースの切り替えの反映にすこしラグがありました．)

カーソルの色に入力ソースの状態を反映するプラグイン: [imestatus](https://github.com/Cassin01/imestatus.vim)